# Finding variance with method of moments

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

[image]

In part (a), I know Var(Ni)=p(p-1) but how do I find the variance of the estimator with this result?

And for part (b) of this question, I have to clue on how to tackle this question. I don't get the precise meaning of the V=max(N1,N2,N3) in the question.

Comment: What is the estimator mentioned in a) expressed in $N_1,N_2,N_3$? On b) can you figure out the probability of the event $N_1=N_2=N_3=0$?

Comment: @drhab the estimator of p is N bar and N bar= (N1+N2+N3)/3 ?

Comment: @drhab for b) is it (1-b)^3 ? But I still don't understand what is max(N1,N2,N3)

Comment: Then $Var(\overline{N})=Var(\frac13(N_1+N_2+N_3))=\frac19(Var(N_1+N_2+N_3)=\frac19(Var(N_1)+Var(N_2)+Var(N_3))$ right? The last equality because of independence.

Comment: $V$ is a random variable. It takes value $0$ if $N_1=N_2=N_3=0$ and it takes value $1$ otherwise. I have to go now and hope you can come out of this. Cheers.